# Can not show bold text on Webview Android

Tags: android, webview, css

I have a html file with css file. I want to load it into Webview. In the css file, i set font-weight for some elements in html file. But the problem is the webview cannot show the bold text that i set. In the list devices i tested: Nexus S, Nexus 4, Nexus 5, Nexus 7, Samsung S3, LG, only Nexus 7 can display the bold text.

I research many times but still no result. Do you have any ideas for this. Thanks you.

Here is my html file:

```
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<section id="answer_box"><!--解答ボックス-->
    <p class="explain_title">正解</p>
    <p class="answer_p"><span class="answer_no">イ</span>  </p>

</section>
<section class="question_title_box">
    <p class="question_main_title"><span class="question_no">１</span>リスニングテスト（放送による指示に従って答えなさい。）</p>
</section><!--question_title_box終わり-->
```

Here is my css file

```
p.question_title_box{
        font-size: 15px;

        font-weight: 600
    }
```

Here is how i load html file:

```
wvQuestion = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.question_content);
WebSettings webSettings = wvQuestion.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String url = "test.html";
wvQuestion.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your css file is stored in `assets/css`, you should be able to load it through [loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). E.g.

```
wvQuestion.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/css/", url, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: ```public void loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data,
            String mimeType, String encoding, String failUrl) {
    }
```
I think this method load HTML from String data, not from HTML url file. 
I try to use it but it cannot load the HTML file.
I also try to parse the HTML file to String data, and load it with the above method but seems it didn't work.